# Build error when compiling Xcode project containing iOS 8 App Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension

I'm currently trying to build an application that contains an iOS 8 app extension, but am running into a bit of an issue. Whenever I try to build and run (whether on device or in simulator), I get the following build error:

```
Ld /Users/Cory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lockdown-aklxfnafpdlclwhfylbcjtzskpmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Lockdown\ Auth.appex/Lockdown\ Auth normal arm64
    cd "/Users/Cory/Documents/Programming/Cocoa App/Lockdown/Lockdown"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/Cory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lockdown-aklxfnafpdlclwhfylbcjtzskpmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Cory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lockdown-aklxfnafpdlclwhfylbcjtzskpmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/Cory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lockdown-aklxfnafpdlclwhfylbcjtzskpmb/Build/Intermediates/Lockdown.build/Debug-iphoneos/Lockdown\ Auth.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Lockdown\ Auth.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -dead_strip -ObjC -framework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit -e _NSExtensionMain -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fapplication-extension -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Cory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lockdown-aklxfnafpdlclwhfylbcjtzskpmb/Build/Intermediates/Lockdown.build/Debug-iphoneos/Lockdown\ Auth.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Lockdown\ Auth_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Cory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lockdown-aklxfnafpdlclwhfylbcjtzskpmb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Lockdown\ Auth.appex/Lockdown\ Auth

ld: framework not found /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is with no additional code inside of the extension target, simply creating an extension, then building gives me this error every time.

Has anyone else seen this issue before? I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary for this to be happening.

Comment: Does the path in "framework not found" exist for you? The error suggests it doesn't exist. On my mac there is a framework file there. Run `ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit` in Terminal and check for a "no such file or directory" error

Comment: It does look like there is not file or directory present at that path. Should reinstalling Xcode fix this issue?

Comment: Yep, either re-install Xcode or re-install the iOS 8 SDK (I'm not even sure how to re-install the SDK though). If you have a recent backup of `/Applications/Xcode.app` you could just try restoring to that.

Comment: Note that you can install a fresh copy of Xcode without uninstalling the old one. Just rename `/Applications/Xcode.app` to something else (or zip it or whatever) then install Xcode again.

Comment: Tried this with a fresh copy from the Mac App Store, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your today extension's *Build settings > Other* linker flags Xcode may have copied that from your existing app, it should be blank.